# Improving a Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I have a make file that I am trying to a make more flexible. So, if I am building an executable, there is primary.c and primary.h. Along with that, there are two other pairs of files that I need to build into the executable: helper_funcs.c / helper_funcs.h and fork.c / fork.h.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -c -g -Wall -Wextra
SOURCES = fork.c helper_funcs.c
DEPS = primary.h fork.h helper_funcs.h 
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE = primary

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.c.o: $(DEPS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
        rm -f *.o
        rm -f $(EXECUTABLE)
```

My goal is to write this make file such that no matter how many additional source files I may have, all I have to do is add them to the SOURCES list and the Makefile will handle the compilation and linking.

When I go to compile this, I get the following:

```
rm -f *.o
rm -f primary
gcc -c -o fork.o fork.c -c -g -Wall -Wextra
gcc -c -o helper_funcs.o helper_funcs.c -c -g -Wall -Wextra
gcc -c -o primary.o primary.c -c -g -Wall -Wextra
primary.c: In function ‘build_state’:
primary.c:114: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘make_passive’
primary.c:120: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘make_active’
primary.c:127: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘string_builder’
primary.c: In function ‘main’:
primary.c:172: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘read_file’
gcc fork.o helper_funcs.o routed_LS.o -o routed_LS
```

The functions that it doesn't see are those included in the helper_funcs.c file. It seems to be picking up the functions in fork.c, but I can't understand where the difference lies.
Can anyone help me figure out how to clear these errors? Thanks!

Comment: it doesn't seem to be a makefile problem. where did you declare those function? you need to include it in primary.c

Comment: You're right. I was compiling that differently before, and now using this method I need to include it, but neglected to add that line. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that turns out not to exist.